# Returning multiple value to multiple variables

Tags: c

Is it possible to return multiple values from function and assign them to multiple variable?

Lets say i have code which generates 3 numbers

```
int first, second , third
int generator (a,b,c){
int one , two ,three
//code that generates numbers and assign them into one, two three
}
```

and i want to assign value of int one into variable first , two to second and three to third. Is something like this possible using C?

Comment: you can pass the parameters by reference

Comment: No, its not possible to return more than one values from a function, but there are some other ways to do the same.

Comment: Did you even try to find an answer before posting? I typed in "returning multiple values in c" in Google and within 10 seconds found the answer to your question.

Comment: @haccks - _No, its not possible..._.  Semantics.  A struct essentially will work.

Comment: @ryyker But that's technically still one value, isn't it?

Comment: @ryyker; ...... *but there are some other ways to do the same.*

Comment: That's why I prefaced my comment with _semantics_ :)   Yes technically.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the addresses of the variables you want to assign a value to:

```
int generator(int* first, int* second, int* third) {
    int one, two, three;

    /* Initialize local variables here. */

    *first = one;
    *second = two;
    *third = three;

    return something;
}

int main(void) {
    int first, second, third;
    generator(&first, &second, &third);
}
```

Another way would be to create a `struct` and return that `struct`:

```
struct data {
    int one, two, three;
};
```

and return it:

```
struct data generator() {
    int one, two, three;

     /* Initialize local variables here. */

    return (struct data) { one, two, three };
}
```

or fill it in via a function parameter<sup>1</sup>, in analogy to the first method:

```
void generator(struct data* d) {
    int one, two, three;

    /* Fill one, two, and three here. */

    d->one = one;
    d->two = two;
    d->three = three;
}
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> as proposed by @CraigEstey in the comments to this answer</sub>

Comment: Both are good examples.  How about adding a third one where you have: `void generator(struct data *);`?  It's usually cleaner, particularly if caller needs to build up the struct from partial init routines as in: `init1(stp); init2(stp); ...`